# jQuery .load on left click, but normal <a> element behavior on hover and middle/right click

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-4

I know how to make a button that will call a jQuery load function. I also know how to create a normal HTML `a` element.

However I do not know how to combine them so that when the link receives a left click, it will `load()` some data into a specific `div` on the current page, but will otherwise act as a normal `a` to a different page of the same website if it receives a middle or right click (to enable opening the link into a new tab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a jQuery `click` event the `which` property lets you know which mouse button was clicked. `1` is the left, `2` is the middle and `3` is the right.

As such you can listen for the left click and perform your `load()` call:

```js
$('#foo').mousedown(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('left click!');
    // $('#someElement').load(...);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="foo">Click me</a>
```